# Forces and torque on a non-uniform rolling cylinder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

Apart from gravitational force, friction and normal reaction, what would generate torque in the following non-uniform rolling cylinder?

[image]

where P is the centre of mass.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Either gravity generates a torque about the geometric center, or the normal force generates a torque about the center of mass. But not both at the same time. So _where_ are you summing torques about?